# Does $\delta W=pdV$ hold for non-ideal gases

Tags: thermodynamics, work

I have that for quasistatic processes,

$$ \delta W= \textbf{f}\cdot d\textbf{x}  $$

so for a gas $\delta W=pdV$.

Does this only hold ideal gases or will it hold for van der waal's gas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is nothing but a mechanical relation valid for every type of isotropic fluid (even viscous, in the quasi-static regime), so gases in particular, no matter any further state equation.

Comment: So it will hold for Van der waal's gases

Comment: Yes, certainly it does.